# Fetch WorkflowTemplate for different language

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I need to fetch the OOB approval workflow from current web to associate it with my custom list

I tried to fetch it through BaseId but then i got to know that BaseId is not the same for different languages.

Is there any other way to fetch the OOB approval workflow's template for sites created on different languages?

I have also tried GetTemplateByName method but its returning null for any language other than English also.

web.WorkflowTemplates.GetTemplateByName("Approval - SharePoint 2010", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself.

As i mentioned in my question, the BaseId varies from language to language. After trying out different methods and googling it, i didn't find any solution to the problem, so i started investigating it myself.

During my investigation, I fetched the BaseId for approval workflow for different languages and soon a pattern emerged. It turned out that BaseId (Guid) is almost same for every language except last three digits and those three digits were basically hexadecimal representation of LCID !!

So, this is how template based id can be formed

string baseId = "8ad4d8f0-93a7-4941-9657-cf3706f00" + web.Language.ToString("X");
Guid workflowBaseId = new Guid(baseId);

so, once we have the base id, we can use the same method to retrieve the template: 
web.WorkflowTemplates.GetTemplateByBaseID(workflowBaseId);

I also wrote the blog post on this one here, in case you would like to see the entire piece of code for workflow association: http://sanjaybhagia.wordpress.com/2013/10/20/associating-oob-approval-workflow-with-custom-list-for-different-locale-lcids/

Hope it helps.

Regards,
Sanjay